# Chef Vagrant Couldn't resolve host 'www.getchef.com'

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, vagrantfile

When I'm running:

```
:$ vagrant provision

or 

:$ vagrant up
```

I'm getting this error:

```
nisevi@localhost processor (master):$ vagrant provision
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't resolve host 'www.getchef.com'
```

if anyone knows to what is related this error, I'm gonna be very grateful.

###################################EDIT

A colleague gave me this thread:

https://serverfault.com/questions/453185/vagrant-virtualbox-dns-10-0-2-3-not-working

as reference where I was able to find some interesting information about mi issue. But now I'm dealing with other problem: bit.ly/1BxehY0

Comment: Your box can't resolve the name, obvisouly a DNS problem. Without any information on your vragrant/virtualbox configuration and your network (proxy or not) it 's more or less trying to guess with a crystal ball to answer.

Comment: show the content in file `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: thanks for your answers but I did some modifications in my Vagrantfile and I have other problem as you can see here: http://bit.ly/1BxehY0

Answer (score 0):

Likely your VM doesn't have any network access due to an incorrect config and an incorrectly installed VirtualBox. Try commenting out the Chef provisioner and then log in to the VM using `vagrant ssh`. See if you can reach the internet from inside and if not, fix that before progressing. If you include the content of the Vagrantfile we might be able to help more.

Comment: hey @coderanger I did what you say, and also I did some modifications in Vagrantfile and now mi errors are others :S .... I was able to do "vagrant ssh" as you can see here: 
vagrant@ubuntu1404-opsworks:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (64.233.176.105) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.google.com (64.233.176.105): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=187 ms
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 8014ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 184.779/186.709/191.663/2.156 ms

but now mi problem is: http://bit.ly/1BxehY0

Answer (score 0):

For me following worked:

- Did vagrant ssh (It threw error to do vagrant up).
- Again did vagrant up.

That's all.